# Posting a post to Blogger

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, google-api, blogger

I am currently using the following library to carrying out my API request to Blogger (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/Downloads?tm=2).

However there is next to no documentation on the Blogger API in this library and from what I have seen there are no examples of this library being used to interact with the blogger site.

How do I go about using this library to implement a function that would post a new post to a users blog?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with Blogger Atom Api version, it is very simple to post contents to Blogger using the Atom api / feeds

To create a new post on a blog create a request as follows

POST /atom/3187374 HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/xml
Host: www.blogger.com
Authorization: BASIC c3RldmVqOm5vdGFyZWFscGFzc3dvcmQ=

atom test
  2004-04-12T06:07:20Z
  Your client's name here.
  
    Testing the Atom API

If you need any thirdparty software for creating blog posts, you can use refer this document 
http://webtoolsin.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/get-rss-to-blogger-script/